# UITableView height problems in Retina 3.5-inch

Tags: uitableview, ios7, height, xcode5

If you look at the screenshot, showing a list of US states, "WV" is not the last row, there are two more rows after: "WI" and "WY" which extend beyond the bottom of the layout. This used to work with Xcode4/iOS6 regardless of whether or not you were in 3.5-inch or 4-inch. Now this only seems to work for 4-inch but not 3.5-inch.

Does anyone know how to get the height behaving correctly for Retina 3.5-inch?

The orange background in the storyboard screenshot below is the View background color.

[image: storyboard screenshot]

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Comment: You should place your `UITableView` for the whole view not like in iOS 6 under the `NavigationBar`. I have had similiar issue. I guess it is a some sort of bug.

Comment: Ah... interesting. That seems to work just fine for the Retina 4-inch simulator. Does anyone know how to get this to work for the Retina 3.5-inch display?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the buttons in the lower right-hand side of the interface builder. Specifically, you can use the "Pin" button to create constraints to the top/bottom and other gui objects.

Constraints in Xcode4 used to auto-create if you dragged an object to the edge of the screen but not anymore in Xcode5 which is why I was confused.